# Saving Auth info to authenticate with each HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, security, authentication, webforms

I'm attempting to create a web form that uses REST to interface with our custom database, and with each web request it requires custom headers to authenticate the request. I only want the user to need to log in once. As of right now, as a work around, I have the credentials being stored in a `Hidden Field`, and then use that value for each request. This seems a bit unsafe to me.

**What other alternatives do I have for this?**

Comment: Depends on the API - is there no login functionality that gives you a session token?

Comment: It requires the credentials be passed for each request. No token API @SilverlightFox

Comment: If you have to do that, then you need to store the credentials somehow. A hidden field is just as secure as other means of storage within the client-side environment (read - not secure at all - anyone with access to the browser can gain the credentials, however way of storing it).

Comment: @SilverlightFox I'm not sure what you mean by the piece in parenthesis

Comment: If you _need_ to send the credentials every time then this seems like poor API design. The most secure way you can implement this on your side is by asking the user for their password _every_ time. Any storage mechanism within the browser itself is not secure from physical access.